# PHP Function - Unknown Failure

Tags: php, function, variables, include, google-analytics

I'm fairly new to coding and just recently started working on integrating functions into my PHP. I am trying to encode and echo an IP address to Google Analytics's. This is what my custom modifier looks like:

```
pagetracker._setCustomVar(1, "IP", "<?php include function.php; echo remove_numbers_advanced($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); ?>", 2);
```

The function file looks like this:

```
<?
function remove_numbers_advanced($string)
{
    $numbers = array();
    for($counter =0; $counter <= 10; $counter++) {
        $numbers[$counter] = $counter;


    $replacements = array("A","7","B","6","C","4","D","3","E","F");
    $string = str_replace($numbers, $replacements, $string);
    return $string;
}';

echo remove_numbers_advanced($string);
?>
```

When I isolated the PHP section of my custom variable in an attempt to test it the page throws a 500 error, suggesting to me that there is something wrong with how I have my script set up.

Please bear in mind I am rather new to this so simple terms and examples would help a ton!

Comment: The syntax highlighting of SO shows one error - you have a stray `';` after you close your function. Is this a typo?

Comment: So far I have changed the function to the code suggested by @D3-k

and added brackets in the proper location in the include, however errors are still returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few errors in your function. The correct function is:

```
function remove_numbers_advanced($string)
{
    $numbers = array();
    for($counter =0; $counter <= 10; $counter++) 
        $numbers[$counter] = $counter;


    $replacements = array("A","7","B","6","C","4","D","3","E","F");
    $string = str_replace($numbers, $replacements, $string);
    return $string;
}
```

1- You added open curly braces next to for loop but did not close it

2- Also there is " '; " at the closing braces of function. It shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I've added your modifications however I am still getting errors! Much appreciated for the example though

Answer (score 0):

include function must have a string parameter so put '' around file name

```
pagetracker._setCustomVar(1, "IP", "<?php include 'function.php'; echo remove_numbers_advanced($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); ?>", 2);
```